# Django REST framework and creating two table entries from a POST form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create entries in two tables (Log and Post) using the DRF Browseable API POST form.

The example below is contrived, but it outlines what I am trying to do.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    info = models.CharField()

class Log(TimeStampedModel):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(('IP Address'))
    name = models.CharField()
    data = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

I want to use the browseable API to submit a form to create a Log entry. Here are the serializers:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('info',)

class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                          
    data = serializers.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ('ip', 'name', 'data')
```

The problem with the above is that `serializer.Field` is read only so does not show up on the POST form. If I change it to CharField it shows up, but then I get an error because an instance of a Post is expected not just a field of the Post object.

Here are my views:

```
class LogMixin(object):
    queryset = Log.objects.all()                                           
    serializer_class = LogSerializer



class LogList(LogMixin, ListCreateAPIView):
    pass


class LogDetail(LogMixin, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    pass
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: see here also may help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/24217852/3904109

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell you want to create a nested Log object. There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Send 2 `POST` Requests, One to create the Post, and the other to create the Log contained the received HTTP 200 data from the API.
2. (Django and best way) Send the data all in one `POST` and parse it server side. Django Rest Framework takes care of this for you.

I have changed your code so that it should work. 
[Source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#NestedRelationships)

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                          
   class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ('ip', 'name')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    log = LogSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('info', 'log')
```

views.py

```
import generics

class PostCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Post
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Then you can send a `POST` Request containing 'info', 'ip', and 'name'.

Comment: Tried that, but the DRF POST form only displays the ip and name fields. The info field is not displayed in the DRF form. I've updated my question with my api views too. Thanks.

Comment: @smithy It looks like your views doesn't relate to your Post serializer. Because of this you are just sending data about your Log objects, but nothing about your Post objects. I will update my code to include the necessary View class.

Comment: I tried this, and I just get info and log shown on the DRF form and under the log field is an error "non_field_errors". Thanks.

Comment: That is a problem with the related name field under the Log model pointing to Post. I edited your code to take this into account. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I get the error with the code example you gave. I don't see any recent edits to my code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky way and the best way to use the nested serializer as stated above.  But just to show another way I am posting it here.

```
    # Add New Item
    @api_view(('POST',))
    def add_new_item(request):
    
    
        request.data['areaname_name'] = request.data['item_areaname']
        request.data['buildingname_name'] = request.data['item_buildingname']
    
        item_serializer = TblItemSerializer(data=request.data)
        area_name_serializer = TblAreanameSerializer(data=request.data)
        building_name_serializer = TblBuildingnameSerializer(data=request.data)

        response = []
        
        if item_serializer.is_valid()  & area_name_serializer.is_valid() & building_name_serializer.is_valid():
    
            # Save To Item  Table
            item_serializer.save()
    
            # Save Unique Values Into Areaname and Buildingname Tables
            area_name_serializer.save()
            building_name_serializer.save()
    
            return Response(item_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            response.append(item_serializer.errors)
            response.append(area_name_serializer.errors)
            response.append(building_name_serializer.errors)

            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In the error response you could also use (depending on how you want to handle on client side)

```
merge = {**item_serializer.errors, **area_name_serializer.errors, **building_name_serializer.errors}
return Response(merge, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```