# POST to Django model with ManyToManyFiled gives Incorrect type. Expected pk value,

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to work out how to do a POST to a Django model containing a ManyToManyField. Everything seems to work except for the ManyToManyField which is throwing an incorrect type error (expected pk value).

My main model that I am POSTing to is:

```js
class Item(models.Model):

    owner           = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')           
    url             = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='', unique=True)                                                                 
    keywords        = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, related_name='keywords')
```

The related Keywords model is:

```js
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.name)
```

The Django REST Framework view for the POST API call is:

```js
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        creator = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.data['owner_id'])
        the_keywords = self.request.data['keywords'].split
        serializer.save(owner=creator)
        serializer.save(keywords=the_keywords)
```

The serializer is:

```js
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_username(self, obj):
        value = str(obj.owner)
        return value

    def get_keywords(self, obj):
        value = str(obj.keywords)
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'item_type', 'title', 'keywords')
```

The Javascript code that makes the POST API call looks like this:

```js
  submitImage(url,title,categories){

      var userID = 18;

      //console.log('in stuff');

      let body = JSON.stringify({url: url, owner_id: serID, title: title, keywords: categories});

      console.log('BODY: '+body);

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.http.post(API_ENDPOINT+'items/ ',
        body, {
          headers: headers
        })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            
          },
          err => {
            alert('ERROR from submitImage() API call: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
          },
          () => {
            
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

This function is called as follows:

```js
     var categories  = ['news','politics'];
     submitImage('http://www.url.com/item','Test item',categories);
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `save_m2m=True` to your save method?https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1556

Comment: Where exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
class keywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model:Keyword
        fields:('name')

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    keywords = keywordSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'item_type', 'title', 'keywords')
```

and your view would look like this:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        creator = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.data['owner_id'])
        the_keywords = self.request.data['keywords'].split
        serializer.save(owner=creator)
```

Comment: In the def get_keywords() function instead of the value = str()?

Comment: I have added your suggestion to the top of the serializer but I am now getting the error "Object with name=['news', 'politics'] does not exist.\"

Comment: @BillNoble here I edited the answer, is your code like this ?

Comment: @BillNoble i think, you want to do a post in two tables at once,  i recomment this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217852/django-rest-framework-and-creating-two-table-entries-from-a-post-form

Comment: @BillNoble i edited it again, try it now like this, and check for typos in my code.