# Django REST: Creating db entries in related table in one POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-post

I have two models, one is pointing to other model.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  field1 = models.CharField()
  field2 = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
  field3 = models.CharField()
  field4 = models.CharField()
  modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

I am using Django REST for data manipulation. I am trying to insert data to `ModelA` and `ModelB` using one ajax call. For one entry in `ModelA`, I have a list of entries in `ModelB`. So my ajax data is,

```
ajax_data = {modela: {....}, modelb: [{...}, {...}, ...]}
```

When I am using only one model, I am able to save, otherwise I am not. Can I save two related model in one one POST request?

Comment: Are you using django rest model serializer?

Comment: yes.. I am using ModelSerializer

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I'm going to [use the non-accepted answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217925/1293222).

[The Django docs state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) that you need to *save* the dependent model (A, in your case), before you can save the related model (B, in your case.)

> Note that you must save an object before it can be assigned to a
>   foreign key relationship. For example, creating an Article with
>   unsaved Reporter raises ValueError:

```
>>> r3 = Reporter(first_name='John', last_name='Smith', email='john@example.com')
>>> Article.objects.create(headline="This is a test", pub_date=date(2005, 7, 27), reporter=r3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'reporter'.
```

As the other answer says - you can either do this in two POSTs or handle it in the view.  It's hard to give specifics without seeing your view code, but [the DRF docs have this covered.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#NestedRelationships)

I've adapted Robert's code for use here.  If it was an accepted answer, I'd just have linked it as a duplicate.

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                          
   class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('field1', 'field1')


class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bclass = ASerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'etc')
```

views.py

```
import generics

class BCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = ModelB
    serializer_class = BSerializer
```

Comment: This is the solution :)