# Adding data to multiple tables using django rest serializers

Tags: reactjs, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am working on django rest framework coupled with react frontend. I am building a simple web service for a medium-sized organisation.

Here is my **Invoice** model from **models.py**

```
class Invoice(models.Model):

    invoice_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    builty_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total_amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date', 'customer']
```

**InvoiceDetail** from **models.py**

```
class InvoiceDetail(models.Model):

    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    num_thaan = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gazaana_per_thaan = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
```

**Ledger** model

```
class Ledger(models.Model):

    TYPE = (
    ('D','Debit'),
    ('C','Credit'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    detail = models.TextField()
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE)
    amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
```

Now I will be having a **form** on my front-end which will be sending `customer_id` and an array of `InvoiceDetail` which I want to fill my database with. So, I will be using information from that form and use it to fill up multiple entries in my `InvoiceDetail` and the `total_amount` would also be calculated from the invoice detail. After this, I would also fill up the ledger based on
the `total_amount`. Right now, I am unable to figure out a way to do this as I am just able to manipulate a single table via a **viewset**

P.S. I am using these serializers right now with `DefaultRouter()`

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

    
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'


class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = '__all__'


class ExpenseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = '__all__'


class InvoiceSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

And this is my `views.py`

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()


class WarehouseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = WarehouseSerializer
    queryset = Warehouse.objects.all()


class ExpenseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = ExpenseSerializer
    queryset = Expense.objects.all()
```

Comment: please share the answer, i am in the same situation.

Comment: I did not get any answer, just went with custom views and used very thick views. I manually managed all the data and updated all the tables that needed to be updated

Comment: see here also may help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/24217852/3904109

Answer (score 1):

In Django REST Framework (DRF), by using **Nested Relationships** of **Serializer Relations** data can be added to multiple tables having relationships.

In **Nested Relationships**, the referred entity can be embedded or nested in the representation of the object that refers to it. Such nested relationships can be expressed by using serializers as fields. If we want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field we need to have `create()` and/or `update()` methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved. It may be noted that by default nested serializers are read-only.

Below is the implementation of the relationship between `Invoice` and `InvoiceDetail`.

```
class InvoiceDetailSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceDetail
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("invoice", )
```

It is required to make `invoice` readonly in `InvoiceDetailSerialiser`.

```
class InvoiceSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoice_details = InvoiceDetailSerialiser(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('invoice_id', 'customer', 'date', 'builty_num', 'total_amount', 'invoice_details')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        invoice_details_data = validated_data.pop('invoice_details')
        invoice= Invoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for invoice_detail_data in invoice_details_data :
            InvoiceDetail.objects.create(invoice=invoice, **invoice_detail_data )
        return invoice
```

If the field is used to represent a to-many relationship, we should add the `many=True` flag to the serializer field.

Based on the above explanation, rest of the implementations can be developed.

More details on this topic from the official guide can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).