# django rest framework saving data to multiple tables from a single view

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm currently new to DRF I am looking to save data to two database tables via the viewset and I don't know how to go about it. I am using react for my frontend
here is my models

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_no = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    farmer_id = models.ForeignKey(Farmer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_per_kgs = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    kgs = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    packaging = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    transport = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

and here is my serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers

# Create your serializers here
from barakasalessystemApp.models import Farmer, Customer, Bill, Payments, Orders
class FarmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Farmer
        fields = "__all__"


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = "__all__"
class OrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response["farmer"] = FarmerSerializer(instance.farmer_id).data
        return response
```

this is my views

```
from functools import partial

from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication

from barakasalessystemApp.models import Farmer, Customer, Payments, Orders
from barakasalessystemApp.serializers import FarmerSerializer, CustomerSerializer, PaymentsSerializer, OrdersSerializer

class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        customer = Customer.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, many=True, context={"request": request})
        response_dict = {"error": False, "message": "All Customers List Data", "data": serializer.data}
        return Response(response_dict)

    def create(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Customer Data Stored Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "An Error Occurred"}

        return Response(dict_response)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        customer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, context={"request": request})
        return Response({"error": False, "message": "Single Data Fetch", "data": serializer.data})

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            queryset = Customer.objects.all()
            customer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Customer Data Updated Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "An Error Occurred"}

        return Response(dict_response)

class OrdersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        orders = Orders.objects.all()
        serializer = OrdersSerializer(orders, many=True, context={"request": request})
        response_dict = {"error": False, "message": "All Orders List Data", "data": serializer.data}
        return Response(response_dict)

    def create(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = OrdersSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Order Stored Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "An Error Occurred"}

        return Response(dict_response)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Orders.objects.all()
        orders = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = PaymentsSerializer(orders, context={"request": request})
        return Response({"error": False, "message": "Single Data Fetch", "data": serializer.data})

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            queryset = Orders.objects.all()
            orders = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
            serializer = OrdersSerializer(orders, data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Order Updated Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "An Error Occurred"}

        return Response(dict_response)
```

I want to store the customer data from the orders table without having to input it again cause its all the same

Comment: see here also may help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/24217852/3904109

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializers for this type of functionality ,And then need to override create and save method